# I made a mistake. I transferred sol to token spl address. How can I recover it?

Tags: spl-token, transfer

I transferred sol from Binance, but by mistake I transferred them to the token address.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to close the token account and get the sol in that account back.

Transfer your tokens out and then close it. See *[How to close SPL token accounts to redeem SOL](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-close-spl-token-accounts-to-redeem-sol)*.