# How to use recover-lamports in Token2022 cli?

Tags: token-2022

I just sent wrong SOL to the token program owned PDA (Token 2022)

I found the url https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/4094
And follow the url, I know that we can with draw SOL by using "recover-lamports command to CLI"

But I don't know how to use it. Please give me more detail!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What kind of PDA was it? A mint account?

Answer (score 2):

You best shot is probably transfer all the tokens out and then close the token account. That should give you your sol back.

Here is a similar question:
[How to close SPL token accounts to redeem SOL](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-close-spl-token-accounts-to-redeem-sol)

Comment: Could you add the actual CLI commands to do so? We try to avoid link-only answers on stackexchange